# Heavy Disk IO causes Silent Reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, raid

We have a server running Ubuntu 16.04 that we run a lot of experiments on, with 4 xeons and 2 RAID controllers (each filled with 1TB SSDs). We have run jobs using all 64 cores for months on end without problem. We've been using it for over a year without any issue until we attempted a new workload.

When performing a large amount of disk IO (hundreds of GB to a TB) in a short time frame, the sever does a silent reboot. We can't find the reboot in any logs. Running "last reboot" doesn't even recognize that a reboot happened, but checking uptime will show that it did restart recently.

Heavy Disk IO will consistently cause the silent reboots. We tried re-building the raid partition. We replaced 1 drive that looked a little weird compared to the others (but still seemed to work). And upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. We also updated the firmware on the RAID controllers and SSDs, but this didn't help.

The reboots still happen, and we aren't really sure how to figure out why. Nothing seems to be recording a problem, and I was hoping someone here has seen this before or know more precisley where to look other than syslog and dmesg (the latter of which is empty).

Comment: Do you monitor the temperatures?

Comment: If there is no record of it, how can you be sure a reboot has occurred? Do you see the BIOS screen? Maybe the active programs have terminated without a restart of the whole system. It's well worth checking the SMART data on all your discs, but especially on your swap disc.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no, I'm not sure how to do that. But the server is running in a cooled center.

Comment: @AFH SMART says everything is fine on all the disks. The reboot occurred b/c uptime shows the reboot, and if we look at the BIOS screen it is infact restarting, and we see the restart process in the logs. But before the restart happens, the server doesn't indicate that it is going to reboot

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski my coworker just checked. CPUs and memory are within the normal range. Power draw is well below workloads we've done before. Case and motherboard temperatures are in the bottom half of the recommended temperature ranges. There doesn't appear to be any report on the RAID controller or SSD temperatures.

Comment: Your statement that `syslog` is empty is misleading: after a reboot it can't be. Many years ago we found a problem with disc write caching, where we proved that reading a sector did not check the write cache, so losing pending updates. We devised a simple test program to read a sector, update it and force a write, then read it back and compare the value, all in a tight loop. In our case it caused database corruptions, but you can imagine how much worse it would be on a swap disc. I'm not saying that this is your problem, but it may be worth trying your tests on different disc configurations.

Comment: @AFH dmesg is empty, not syslog. 
We also managed to check all the SSDs and both RAID controllers, all are at safe temperatures.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `dmesg` is empty: `dmesg` is a program which controls and displays kernel logs; `syslog` is one of the log files in `/var/log/` and it contains kernel log messages, as well as messages from other origins. I have never seen an empty kernel log.

Comment: There was another post somewhere that said to check /var/log/dmesg, but that was empty. I'm not an expert in this, that's why I'm posting.